# useTranslation hook react-i18next

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

why does it not work? I try to cut my translation path. How can I do that without passing whole path ("root.chapter.key")?

```js
// json
{"root":
  "chapter": {
     "key": "Some text"
  }
}

const { t } = useTranslation('root')

const text = t('chapter.key')

// or

const { t } = useTransaltion('root.chapter')

const text = t('key')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First argument of `useTranslation` function [must always be a namespace to load](https://react.i18next.com/latest/usetranslation-hook#loading-namespaces). If you want to shorten your JSON path, you can use [`keyPrefix` option](https://react.i18next.com/latest/usetranslation-hook#optional-keyprefix-option) instead.

```
const { t } = useTranslation('namespace', {
  keyPrefix: 'root.chapter'
})

const text = t('key');
```

If you haven't explicitly defined your namespace, default value for it is `translation`.